# How does flink recognize hiveConfDir when running in yarn cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have following code to test flink and hive integration. I submit the application via `flink run -m yarn-cluster ....`. The hiveConfDir is a local directory that resides on the machine that I submit the application, I would ask how flink can able to read this local directory when the main class is running in the cluster(yarn-cluster)? Thanks!

```
package org.example.app

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.HiveCatalog
import org.apache.flink.types.Row

object FlinkBatchHiveTableIntegrationTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    val name = "myHiveCatalog"
    val defaultDatabase = "default"
    //how does flink could read this local directory
    val hiveConfDir = "/apache-hive-2.3.7-bin/conf"
    val hive = new HiveCatalog(name, defaultDatabase, hiveConfDir)
    tenv.registerCatalog(name, hive)
    tenv.useCatalog(name)

    val sql =
      """
      select * from testdb.t1

      """.stripMargin(' ')

    val table = tenv.sqlQuery(sql)
    table.printSchema()


    table.toAppendStream[Row].print()

    env.execute("FlinkHiveIntegrationTest")

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks I find the answer. The application is submitted with `flink run -m yarn-cluster`.By this way, the main method of the application is running at the client side where the hive is installed,so the hive conf dir could be read.